# how to make div clickable after hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

how to make this img clickable after hover?

```html
<div class="mix col-lg-6 col-md-6 digital">
  <a href="img/Photography/hotel2/LRM_EXPORT_150328983362756_20180927_162750874.jpeg" class="portfolio-item set-bg " data-setbg="img/Photography/hotel2/LRM_EXPORT_150328983362756_20180927_162750874.jpeg">
    <div class="pi-inner">
      <h2>OPEN GALLERY</h2>
    </div>      
  </a>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: What exactly is _hovring_?? Do you mean hovering?

Comment: ------i mean hover

Answer (score 0):

Add a click event to the a tag like,

```
<a href="img/Photography/hotel2/LRM_EXPORT_150328983362756_20180927_162750874.jpeg" class="portfolio-item set-bg " data-setbg="img/Photography/hotel2/LRM_EXPORT_150328983362756_20180927_162750874.jpeg" onclick="doStuff()">
```

In the doStuff(), do whatever you need to happen when the image is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

using javascript, you could do it like this:

```
var clickable = false;
var img = document.getElementById('IdOfyourELement');

img.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(){
    clickable = true;
});
img.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(){
    clickable = false;
});

img.addEventListener('click', function(){
    if(clickable) {
        //doWhatEverThing
    }
});
```

You could also try and add the variable clickable to your element to avoid using globals.
Like this:

```
img.clickable = false;
img.clickable = true;
```